How to pass a parameter in dotnet build which can be accessed by C# code?
I'm building an installer using dotnet build command. I'd like to set the version of the installer dynamicly so I tried doing dotnet build -p:MyProp="1.0.0.0 but what this does is only overwrite my property in the .csproj file? Am I right?
I saw some other threads indicating that .csproj property values can't be accessed during runtime.
TLDR; I need to pass a variable using dotnet build and access it my C# code. Any ideas?

As you can see here c#'s preprocessor cannot do this

But you can set version of assembly(or product or file)and read it at runtime

How would I do that?

You're almost there, if you need to access the value during the runtime of the program u can try:
dotnet build /p:Version=1.0.0.0 /p:MyVersion=1.0.0.0

and to access it in the code
string version = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyVersion");

Let me know if you need anything else or need to modify this value during the run of the program

Environment variables aren't provided by building... you're specifying an MSBuild property, which is only present at build time, and is entirely different to an environment variable. This code just will not work.

Confirmed. It's not in the env variables
